# How to try-catch and continue the script in php

Tags: php, error-handling, try-catch

I am querying an API but some times the API sends 503, 400 etc errors after random hours of script execution.

I have tried to catch it, but no matter how i try, my script is stopping and i need to keep checking manually if the script stopped.

Is there a way to CATCH every error occurred in the Try block ?

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: Client error: `GET
>   http://xxxxxxxxxx` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:

```
    while ($x <= 5000) {
    try {
        sleep(2);
        $formattedResponse = $apaiIO - > runOperation($lookup);
        $xml = simplexml_load_string($formattedResponse);
    } catch (\GuzzleHttp\ Exception\ ServerException $e) {
        $code = $e - > getResponse() - > getStatusCode();
        echo "<strong>Error:</strong> ".$e - > getResponse() - > getReasonPhrase().
        " <strong>Code:</strong> ".$code.
        "<br>";
        switch ($code) {
            // throttle request/service unavailable;
            case 503:
                sleep(2);
            default:
                sleep(2);
                throw new Exception($e - > getResponse() - > getReasonPhrase(), $code);
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        sleep(2);
        //Last error was thrown by this line.

        throw new Exception($e - > getMessage(), $e - > getCode());
    }

    //do script stuff here.
}
```

Comment: Well, you're catching the exception (probably), but then you're throwing another one in each case…

Comment: Yes thanks for pointing out the problem

Answer (score 0):

Using continue and keeping the whole try-catch in another loop should not break the script any more.

```
$success=false;
    $cattempt=0;// current attempt;
    while($cattempt<=2){
        try{
            sleep(2);
            $xml = simplexml_load_string($formattedResponse);
            $success=true;
        }catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ServerException $e) {
            $code=$e->getResponse()->getStatusCode();
            echo "<strong>Error:</strong> ".$e->getResponse()->getReasonPhrase()." <strong>Code:</strong> ".$code."<br>";
            switch($code){
                // throttle request/service unavailable;
                case 503:
                    sleep(2);
                    $cattempt++; // will try again.
                    break; // break from switch
                default: 
//                  sleep(2);
//                  $cattempt++;
                    break 2; // break from swtich and while loop
//                  throw new Exception($e->getResponse()->getReasonPhrase(),$code);
            }
        }
        catch (\Exception $e) {
            echo "<strong>Error:</strong> ".$e->getMessage()." <strong>Code:</strong> ".$e->getCode()."<br>";
            sleep(2);
            break; // break from while;
//          throw new Exception($e->getMessage(),$e->getCode());
        }
        if($success) break;
    }
    if(!$success){
        continue; // go to next ASIN.
    }
```